# Array sorts incorrectly/unpredictably when using indexOf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, sorting

I'm trying to sort autocomplete suggestions using the Array sort method and indexOf. The user's current search term would be plugged into the indexOf.

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/neowot/km1uvzo0/

It seems to half-work. For instance, if you type "Eternal" you get a seemingly correctly sorted list. But if you then delete the 'l' from that term, the list immediately becomes jumbled.

However, it doesn't only mess up on 2nd searches... For instance, if you start clean and just search 'A', the suggestion "Mechanic: Resurrection" is shown as the 2nd suggestion.

And bizarrely, if you search "200", you get the result "Payuk Mhek" in 3rd -- again.

I cannot figure out why these errors are occurring. Please let me know if you can help. Thank you.

```
function AutoComplete() {
    $(".searchbox").autocomplete({  
        source: function(request, response) {  
            $.when(GetMovies(request), 
                   GetTV(request))
            .done(function() {   
                combine = results1.concat(results2).slice(0, 15);   

                combine.sort(function(a, b){    
                    if (b.value.indexOf(request.term) - a.value.indexOf(request.term) < 1) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if (b.value.indexOf(request.term) - a.value.indexOf(request.term) > 1) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });

                response(combine);   
                console.log(combine);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `results1` and `results2` are not defined in your code, `combine` should be a `var`.

Comment: @Tomalak, they are in his full code fiddle, as this is just a small extract of the complete code.

Comment: No, you're using global variables because you're doing it wrong. Compare: https://jsfiddle.net/km1uvzo0/1/ The biggest change is embracing the fact that jQuery Ajax requests return promises, see the use of `.then()`. But there are various other small changes, look closely.

Comment: Ah, I see that @Thomas actually offered similar advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example, because you slice the results before they are sorted

i've rewritten your code

```
$(".searchbox").on("input", AutoComplete);

function AutoComplete() {
    $(".searchbox").autocomplete({  
        source: function(request, response) {  
            $.when(GetMovies(request), GetTV(request))
            .done(function(movies, tv) {

                var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
                var combine = movies.concat(tv)
                    .map((v,i) => {
                        //don't have to compute the index for every combination
                        //precompute such values if possible
                        return {
                            titleLowerCase: v.value.toLowerCase(),
                            termOffset: (v.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(term)+1) || Infinity,
                            //and keep a reference to the original data
                            data: v
                        }
                    })
                    .sort((a, b)=>{
                        //sortOn(termOffset ASC, titleLowerCase ASC)
                        return (a.termOffset - b.termOffset) || 
                        (a.titleLowerCase !== b.titleLowerCase && a.titleLowerCase > b.titleLowerCase? 1: -1) || 0;
                    })
                    .map(v => v.data).slice(0, 15);

                response(combine);   
                console.log(combine);
            });
        }
    });
}

function GetMovies(request) {
    //Replace spaces with a '+'
    var url = request.term.replace(/\s/g,"+");
    return $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=420b889ac6f9e4a1e2dc541624d12fc6&query='
        + url,
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).then(function(data) {
        return $.map(data.results || [], function(v,i){
            return {
                label: v.title + ' MOVIE (' + v.release_date + ')',
                value: v.title
            }
        });
    });
}   

function GetTV(request) {
    //Replace spaces with a '+'
    var url = request.term.replace(/\s/g,"+");
    return $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=420b889ac6f9e4a1e2dc541624d12fc6&query='
        + url,
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).then(function(data){
        return $.map(data.results || [], function(v,i){
            return {
                label: v.name + ' TV (' + v.first_air_date + ')',
                value: v.name
            }
        });
    })
}
```

maybe you still need to adjust the sorting by your preferences, but it should return a way more stable result

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm struggling with getting this running... https://jsfiddle.net/neowot/km1uvzo0/2/ Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: i introduced an error with the edit. fixed it in the answer. And you can get rid of these global Arrays, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/km1uvzo0/4/

Comment: but do you understand how it works, and do you understand the changes in structure i've done to your code?

Comment: I'm at about 60 to 70% comprehension of your changes. Some of the stuff I haven't even seen before. I'm going to be studying it until I fully understand. The code `termOffset: (v.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(term)+1) || Infinity,` is confusing to me... Why are offset and infinity used? (Obviously the result is great, but I don't understand the logic) And again, thank you.

Comment: `v.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(term)` should be clear. some of the results in you response don't contain the term in the title, but in some other field, then this offset would return -1. Do you follow? `(-1+1)` is zero and therefore falsy. `0 || Infnity` returns the latter value, Infinity; I do this to ensure, that titles, that don't contain the term are added after any other result that contains the term. any other index is not affected by this; it's only incremented by 1, but in the end the compairson remains the same.

Comment: it's just a fancy way to write: `var offset = v.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(term); if(offset === -1) offset = Infinity;`

Answer (score 2):

What sort are you trying to achieve?

The `indexOf` may not do what you are expecting; it returns the position in the string and -1 if not found, and it is case-sensitive.

Now it is likely that many of the results will have an identical `indexOf` result; you should account for that case by adding another search condition instead of returning `0` in your comparison function, something like this:

```
              combine.sort(function(a, b) {
                a = a.value.toUpperCase();
                b = b.value.toUpperCase();
                var term = request.term.toUpperCase();
                if (a.indexOf(term) > b.indexOf(term)) {
                  return 1;
                } else if (a.indexOf(term) < b.indexOf(term)) {
                  return -1;
                } else if (a > b) {
                  return 1;
                } else if (a < b) {
                  return -1;
                } else {
                  return 0;
                }
              });
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the results on top are the ones that most closely match the user's query.

Comment: @matthew, how do you qualify "most closely" exactly?

Comment: I'd like the results with the search term in the first word sorted at the top, then sort second word results next, and so on. Each grouping would be sorted alphabetically if possible. I think that is what would be best.

Comment: @matthew, ok, I edited my answer to implement the requested behavior. Note the `toUpperCase` calls to make all strings compare case-insensitively, and the replaced conditions on the `indexOf` comparisons.

Comment: "you should account for that case by adding another search condition instead of returning 0 in your comparison function" - what is wrong with underdetermined sorting order as long as it's determined enough for the user's use case?

Comment: @JanDvorak, the issue is that the results may change for the same query, which usually confuses users.